# How to prevent integers being assigned to char strings?

Tags: c++, string

I am very new at programming in c++, and I have come across this problem I can't solve. I am trying to create an error message whenever a user inputs integers instead of characters. The problem is, the integers are being accepted and assigned to the char strings for some reason.. I thought the point of defining the strings as int or char etc. was to let the compiler know what values are to be accepted. Could anyone let me know what i'm doing wrong?

```
int x, input = false;
char check[SIZE], str[SIZE];

cout << "Enter one word: ";
cin >> str;

while (!cin)
{
    cout << "\nERROR: You must enter only one word with characters. \n\nRe-enter: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    cin >> str;
}
```

Comment: C != C++. In C++, you should generally be using `std::string` instead of C style strings. Also, `"123"` is a perfectly valid string. *You* need to check it to make sure it fits your needs.

Comment: 1,2,3, etc... Are characters. At IO level there's no distinction between integers and characters, it's all bytes (or `char`s, since `sizeof(char)==1` byte).

Comment: @aslg `sizeof(char)` is NOT zero

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz Typo. I edited right away.

Comment: `cin.ignore(256, '\n');` is not the correct way to empty the entire stream. What if there are more than 256 characters in it?

Comment: @Neil so I should use SIZE instead?

Comment: Don't use character arrays, they can overflow.  For example, set `SIZE`  to 3 and enter the word "Overflow" and see what happens.  The `cin` doesn't restrict input by quantity.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/ *If this is exactly numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), there is no limit: As many characters are extracted as needed until delim (or the end-of-file) is found.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A char is just a 1-byte interpretation of an integer according to an ascii value (i.e. the integer 68 is the ascii value for the character 'D'). Other ascii values can be found [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

For your code, you will likely need to create a function that loops through the inputted string and checks to see if any of the characters are not letters.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i <  strlen(str); i++)
{
    if ((int)str[i] < 65 || ((int)str[i] > 90 && (int)str[i] < 97) ||  (int)str[i] > 122)
    {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use character constants, prefer `'A'` instead of 65.

Comment: Also, see the functions `std::isalpha` and `std::isdigit`.

Comment: Is it necessary to calculate the length of the string every iteration?

Comment: @NeilKirk Nope. If you want to have fewer operations, you could save the `strlen` to a variable prior to the loop

Answer (score 5):

First, use `std::string` instead of `char[]`.

Second, "2" is a perfectly valid string.

Third, you can use [`find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) or similar to check if the string contains any values that are undesirable.

```
std::string::size_t result = str.find_first_of("0123456789");
if (result != std::string::npos)
{
    // Found an undesirable character
}
```